# How do i get the Roborock Vacuum cleaner token for the Xioami Mi IO Binding

Tags: token, xiaomi, openhab

I want to add my Xiaomi RoboRock vacuum cleaner to the openHab.
After installing the Xiaomi Mi Io Binding, it asks for a token in the configuration.
After seaching the internet they say you need to install a old version on the app, do a backup.....

I there a easier way to get that token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is:

Since App version 5.4.49 the token is stored readable in the log files.

1. Make sure you have the Xiaomi App installed on you Android device
2. Setup your Roborock
3. goto SmartHome\logs\plug_DeviceManager
4. search the logs for the token